# What are the words to a countercurse?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone, Quirrell uses a curse to try to throw Harry off his broom. Severus uses a "*countercurse*" to prevent this from happening.

Since it appears that Quirrell didn't put a specific spell on the broom, but was just muttering a curse, then did it not need a **specific** countercurse? Or was one countercurse universal to resolve the issue?

Anyway, my main question is:

- What does a 'countercurse' sound like and what words are used to cast it?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't type those words.

Comment: "Finite incantatem" :)

Answer (score 2):

Two counter-curses are mentioned in the 8 Potter books (and supplementary materials), specifically [*'Liberacorpus'*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Liberacorpus) which works as a counter for the ['*Levicorpus'*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Levicorpus) spell and '*Emancipare*' which works as a counter for the *'Brachiabindo'* spell.

> *He groped for the potion book and riffled through it in a panic,
> trying to find the right page; at last he located it and deciphered
> one cramped word underneath the spell: praying that this was the
> counter-jinx, Harry thought **Liberacorpus!** with all his might.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince.</sup></sub>

and

> **HARRY:** *Brachiabindo!*
>
> DRACO is bound tightly.
>
> **DRACO:** *That really the best you got? Emancipare.*
>
> DRACO releases his own binds.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child)</sup></sub>

Given that some other counter-curses [are apparently verbal](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Counter-curse), it seems reasonable to assume that the ability to apply a counter requires you to correctly identify the original curse, then to apply a form of words or mental phrasing which specifically *reverses* the effects of that curse.

Comment: For the last paragraph; my thought exactly. That's why I asked, does it need a specific counter curse, because most, if not all do.

Comment: ***6*** Potter books??

Comment: @randal'thor - /Sigh

Answer (score 2):

**There are many spells that could be considered "countercurses," in that they negate or reverse the effects of a curse.**

- Snape seems to know a countercurse for *Sectumsempra*:

  > The door banged open behind Harry and he looked up, terrified: Snape
  >   had burst into the room, his face livid. Pushing Harry roughly aside,
  >   he knelt over Malfoy, drew his wand, and traced it over the deep
  >   wounds Harry’s curse had made, muttering an incantation that sounded
  >   almost like song. The flow of blood seemed to ease; Snape wiped the
  >   residue from Malfoy’s face and repeated his spell. Now the wounds
  >   seemed to be knitting.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

  While this could simply be a generic healing spell, the fact that Snape invented   *Sectumsempra*, and did not fail to have a countercurse for his other invention, *Levicorpus*, suggests otherwise.
- The Stunning Spell (*Stupefy*) can be reversed by *Rennervate*:

  > “Stunned,” he said softly. His half-moon glasses glittered in the
  >   wandlight as he peered around at the surrounding trees.
  >
  > “Should I go and get someone?” said Harry. “Madam Pomfrey?”
  >
  > “No,” said Dumbledore swiftly. “Stay here.”
  >
  > He raised his wand into the air and pointed it in the direction of
  >   Hagrid’s cabin. Harry saw something silvery dart out of it and streak
  >   away through the trees like a ghostly bird. Then Dumbledore bent over
  >   Krum again, pointed his wand at him, and muttered, “*Rennervate*.”
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
- *Levicorpus*, of course, had a counterspell:

  > She raised her wand, pointed it at Harry, and whispered, “*Levicorpus*.”
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > “*Liberacorpus*!” yelled Harry, and with a crash he and Griphook
  >   landed on the surface of the swelling treasure, and the sword flew out
  >   of Harry’s hand.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*
- Petrificus Totalus has *some kind* of countercurse:

  > There was **a flash of red light** and Harry’s body unfroze; he was able
  >   to push himself into a more dignified sitting position, hastily wipe
  >   the blood off his bruised face with the back of his hand, and raise
  >   his head to look up at Tonks, who was holding the Invisibility Cloak
  >   she had just pulled away.
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

  It is very possible that this spell is indeed *Rennervate*, which produced a similar effect when Harry attempted to use it to revive Dumbledore:

  > “No!” shouted Harry, who had stood to refill the goblet again; instead
  >   he dropped the cup into the basin, flung himself down
  >   beside Dumbledore, and heaved him over onto his
  >   back; Dumbledore’s glasses were askew, his mouth agape, his eyes
  >   closed. “No,” said Harry, shaking Dumbledore, “no, you’re not dead,
  >   you said it wasn’t poison, wake up, wake up — Rennervate!” he cried,
  >   his wand pointing at Dumbledore’s chest; there was **a flash of red
  >   light** but nothing happened. “Rennervate — sir — please —”
  >
  > —*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*

All of these **seem to involve a specific incantation**, whether verbal or nonverbal. However, note that Harry tried to use *Rennervate* on Dumbledore when he was unconscious, and Tonks may well have used it to free him from the Full Body-Bind, **so some counterspells may work on multiple curses**.

There does not, however, appear to be some generic formula for counterspells or countercurses (such as saying the words backwards), as there is in some works.

Comment: Finite Incantatem?